# Creating Registry keys SID REG_BINARY

Tags: windows, powershell, acl, regedit

I am creating a new local account via PowerShell and creating their profile in

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\
```

too.

I can grab the SID for the user via; `([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).User.Value`

However, within the SID key of a user, there is a value called `SID`, of type `REG_BINARY`. How is this created? Can someone please help me?

The reason why I need this is I am migrating a domain account to a local user and keeping all settings, but because of this key it's not working.

This is what I have at the moment:

[image: pic1]

This is the key missing which I am not sure where it comes from:

[image: pic2]

Comment: Can you show us what you're talking about? To include an example of what it's suppose to look like?

Comment: Hello @AbrahamZinala I've attached photos in the above question now, apologies and thank you

Comment: Please don't use photos, and attach code/problem codes/results as plain text.

Comment: It's difficult for showing via plain text as it's a list of keys, apologies not sure how I can do this @AbrahamZinala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert a SID to its binary representation and write it to the registry like this:

```
# Replace this with the actual target SID string
$SIDString = 'S-1-5-21-1518175382-1413263562-1473642471-31061' 

# Parse as SecurityIdentifier struct
$SID = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new($SIDString)

# Create a byte array to hold the binary representation
$binarySID = [byte[]]::new($SID.BinaryLength)

# Copy binary SID to byte array
$SID.GetBinaryForm($binarySID, 0)

# Write binary SID to registry
$path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\${SIDString}"
New-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name SID -PropertyType Binary -Value $binarySID
```